# mutable_gravity in tutorial

Tags: gazebo

[image: Gazebo Answers logo]

Hello!

As you guess, I have started to study the tutorials for the gazebo plugins.
I was doing the "Programmatic World Control" (http://gazebosim.org/tutorials?tut=plugins_world_properties&cat=write_plugin)

and in the line that change the gravity:

```
// Change gravity
      msgs::Set(physicsMsg.mutable_gravity(),
          ignition::math::Vector3d(0.01, 0, 0.1));
```

It uses physicsMsg.mutable_gravity()
I searched the API for the definition of mutable_gravity() but I couldn't find something.
As I try to understand what is going on I need to know where I can find these definitions.
Could anybody point me the direction?

Kind regards,
Angelos

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.gazebosim.org/question/16443/mutable_gravity-in-tutorial/) by [Angelos](https://answers.gazebosim.org/users/3366/angelos/) on Gazebo Answers with karma: 17 on 2017-06-15

Post score: 1

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [Lays](https://answers.gazebosim.org/users/14571/lays/) on 2019-08-18**:
good question

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Gazebo Answers logo]

`gazebo::msgs::Physics` is generated using protobuf. The method `mutable_gravity()` is automatically generated from the field `optional Vector3d gravity` in the protobuf file. Here is an [overview of using protubuf in C++](https://developers.google.com/protocol-buffers/docs/cpptutorial). This link [describes the C++ code generated](https://developers.google.com/protocol-buffers/docs/reference/cpp-generated) from protobuf messages. And this link is the [protobuf definition in gazebo 8](https://bitbucket.org/osrf/gazebo/src/0a80f10918576cf1fc4787ebb6f1b9cb424a0c8b/gazebo/msgs/physics.proto?at=gazebo8&fileviewer=file-view-default) for the mesage you're using.

---

Originally posted by [sloretz](https://answers.gazebosim.org/users/1290/sloretz/) with karma: 558 on 2017-06-15

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [Angelos](https://answers.gazebosim.org/users/3366/angelos/) on 2017-06-15**:
Thank you, I'm going to study your links and understand the concept.

**Comment by [Lays](https://answers.gazebosim.org/users/14571/lays/) on 2019-08-18**:
thanks very much